# Rate/Bandwidth limiting with haproxy, what are the options?

Tags: haproxy, access-control-list, host

I have tried reading up on different methods of limiting (rate/bw) with haproxy,
but seems the only working implementation I find is per /32 ip based limit.
Is it possible to do rate limiting based on acl?

Samba has a nice solution to this, where the parameters to limit (based on acl)
is: /0 /24 /32 .. so first variable is for the whole acl, next for /24 net, and
last for single ip.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit sessions with ease, but considering you want to manipulate L3/L4 would it not be more appropriate to handle the limiting at a lower level - ie. With IP tables.

Eg. https://serverfault.com/a/403001/113375